# C++ Vector iteration

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, vector, iterator

I have a vector of int P=[n1,n2,n3]. what is the most efficient way to generate another vector of  , the same size as P, call it v1=[m1,m2,m3].  Step:

1. vector < int> P[N], N ,contains n0, n1, n2
2. for each n_i in N , generate a vector of normal random variable with size n0, then n1, n2
3. Take the sum of each new vector independently, sum (n0), sum( n1), sum( n2)
4. Create a vector  v1[m1,m2,m3].  for each i in "v1" contains the sum of random numbers from previous step.

```
const int N = 10;
vector<int> p;
vector <double> b;

for ( int i =0; i<N ; i++)
        
    {
   
    Poiss  = U.RandomPoisson(Lambda);  // generate N Poissonian Random variables
    
    Normal = U.RandomNormal(4000,7000); // generate N Normal Random variable
    
    p.push_back(Poiss);
    b.push_back(Normal);
    
}
    
// iterate over P and use each element of p call it p[i] as the size of a new random vector with size p[i] call it vec[p[i]].  Take the sum of vec[p[i]] and add to a new vector call it V.   The Final size of V is the same as P 

for ( auto &i : p )
{
            do some stuff...
}
```

Comment: Have you tried writing any code to solve this problem? Also it would be helpful if you showed some examples of input and desired output.

Comment: You should try to write some code first. Right now this seems more like well phrased "give me some code"-kind of question. Also measure if this is really a bottleneck. Also often there is no most efficient way, but you will need a compromise, for example use more memory but less time or vice versa.

Comment: What have you implemented till now in the provided code or is it just "pseudo"?

Comment: This is actual implementation, not sure what you mean by "pseudo?"

Comment: forget the U. that is an instance of a class, of which RandomPoisson and RandomNormal are members.

Comment: @Ainsoph Okay then, what do you want us to do? What's the problem now??

Comment: iterate over vector P.   For each iteration, generate a random vector of size P[i], call it Vec[P[i]] take the sum of Vec[P[i]], and push_back into another vector call it Vec1.

Comment: It's still not clear what problems you encounter with this task. Seems pretty straight forward. What is stopping you from doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need something like this:

```cpp
vector<vector<int>> vec;
vector<int> v;
v.reserve(p.size());
for (auto &&i : p) {
    vector<int> temp(i);
    for (auto &&j : temp) 
        j = U.RandomNormal(4000, 7000);
    v.push_back(accumulate(temp.begin(), temp.end(), 0));
    vec.push_back(move(temp));
}
```

In place of

```cpp
for (auto &&j : temp) 
    j = U.RandomNormal(4000, 7000);
```

you can directly use :

```cpp
std::generate(temp.begin(), temp.end(), [&U] () { return U.RandomNormal(4000, 7000); });
```

If you don't need `vec`, i.e., just need the values inside `v`, then do something like:

```cpp
vector<int> v;
v.reserve(p.size());
for (auto &&i : p) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) 
        sum += U.RandomNormal(4000, 7000);
    v.push_back(sum);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, brc-dd and rest.